# login form requiring loading the page first php curl

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I posted this as php/curl but am open to any working solution.

`example.com/login.asp` has a hidden value inside the login form:
`input type="hidden" name="security" value="123456789abcdef"`

I tried to use curl to get this extra security value and include it to another curl call however the value changed after the first curl. I have read a related post, which suggests using php `file_get_contents` but it didn't work with the specific website.

Current php curl looks like this:

```
function curling ($websitehttps,$postfields,$cookie,$ref,$follow) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $websitehttps);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Connection: Close'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    if ($cookie != "") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookie);
    }
    if ($postfields != "") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I am required to use the extra security code in post fields ($postfields) which should look like something similar to this:
`ref=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&security=123456789abcdef`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you making sure the cookie from the first request is passed to the second one? I assume that if not, that's why the security value would change. Here is what [quick google search gave me](http://coderscult.com/php-curl-cookies-example/).

Comment: @i-- Thanks for the accurate tip, the problem was actually about cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some extra lines to two separate curl sessions solved the problem.

Lines added to the first curl session:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

These additions created a cookie file in tmp folder.

Lines added to the second curl session:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

And here, used the information inside the cookie file to get the same security code on login page.

The solution described at [another website](http://coderscult.com/php-curl-cookies-example/) may also work. In my case, server settings did not let me to use it.